# Increase image size

Tags: html, cocoa

I am using NSTextView to display HTML. The HTML has a base64 encoded image in it.  When I click on a button, I want to be able to increase the size of the embedded image Is this possible ?.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `NSTextView` to display HTML? Why not use `WebView`? That way you can easily change the size of the image using CSS.

The HTML support in `NSTextView` is rudimentary at best.

Comment: I know but what to do. The reasons are more political than technical.